# python com component does not register when using libxml2 on win7

Tags: python, com

i've built a com component which utilizes libxml2 python bindings , the build is successfull but when i try to register the component i get **"specified module could not be found , unable to load python dll"** this is the error i get when **the component is built using the bundle files option set as 1**
if i **build the component with bundle files set as 3** ,then i get a different error saying that **the component was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer Failed with error code 80040201**

if the libxml2 import is removed all works fine.

any help wold be simply great.

thanks

Comment: A bit offtopic, but is there any specific you didn't try http://users.skynet.be/sbi/libxml-python/?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `regsvr32.exe` which registers you COM component couldn't find a DLL that your COM component needs.

I'm not familiar with Python COM components but is there some way you can run `depends.exe` on it?  This is the usual way to track down binary dependency problems.

Comment: i have done that but that's of no use as depends show nothing missing.

Comment: @tristan625: Have you used `depends` to 'profile' the registration rather than simply using it to analyse your DLL?  To do this you must open `regsvr32.exe`, rather than your DLL, with `depends`, then choose Profile from one of the menus.  You'll need to give it the command line arguments you would normally use to register your DLL.  Then it will monitor `regsvr32` as it runs and tries to register you COM component.  This will show you what's _really_ missing.